# is there a more elegant way to write this? variable within activerecord is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I ruby on rails, in view, I would like to check if there is some variable not null.
I suppose first I must check if there is even a object and then check if that r1!=nil.
Is there a better way?
thank you

```
      <% neki=Anketare.where("semestar_id=? AND JMBAG=? AND sifPred=? and vrstaNastave=?",session[:semestar_id],predmett.JMBAG,params[:format],Vrstanastave.find(1).vrstaNastave) %>
  <% if neki.exists? %>
    <% if neki.first.r1!=nil %>
        A+
    <% else %>
    A-
    <% end %>       
    <% else %>
    A-
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Some formatting would help the most.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Ruby), I would suggest something like

Model or controller! -

```
@neki=Anketare.where("semestar_id=? AND JMBAG=? AND sifPred=? and vrstaNastave=?",
session[:semestar_id],predmett.JMBAG,params[:format],
Vrstanastave.find(1).vrstaNastave)
```

View:

```
<%= @neki.exists? ? (@neki.first.r1!=nil ? "A+" : "A-") : "A-" %>
```

might work.

You need the `@` to share the variable between the controller and the view.

Comment: I wish I could give you +1 for the nested ternary (though you might want to put some grouping parens on there for clarity) and another +1 for nothing that determining the grade is definitely not appropriate work for a view.

Comment: thank you..it seems to work...I dont need anything to calculate, just to print...

Comment: +1 yeah I love parens!  I added one set and that is great, thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foo.nil?` to test if something is nil.  So you can call neki.first.r1.nil? to test if it's nil.  You can also just use the item itself as a boolean test:

```
if neki.first.r1; do_something; else; do_something_else; end
```

With rails you can also use `foo.blank?` to check if something is not nil and is not a blank string or empty array.  Rails also gives you `foo.present?` to check if something is not `blank?` (the same as `!foo.blank?`)

So in your case you can simply change the entire set of if statements to:

```
<%= (neki.present? and neki.first.r1) ? "A+" : "A-" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer...did you mean <%= neki.r1.present? ? "A+" : "A-" %>

Comment: No, you can't check neki.r1 because neki is an array (or a proxy that acts as one).  You would first need to make sure neki is not empty (neki.present?) and then call :r1 on any element - in your case the first element - in the neki collection to see if it exists (neki.first.r1)

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Use the [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) :

```
<%= @neki.andand.first.r1 ? "A+" : "A-" %>
```

Comment: Thanks, never knew about that one.  But, how will andand work with @neki which in this case is certainly not nil but might be empty

Comment: @PinnyM `andand` is truthy, not `nil`y. Chain `andand`s as required: `@neki.andand.first.andand.r1`. All this should be wrapped up in a helper as other answers point out.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't include any of the logic in the view. Instead, you can write a model that performs the logic on `neki` and `neki.first.r1` and figures out the grade, then call that from your view.

Example:

```
# Model
class Neki
  def initialize(neki)
    @neki = neki
  end
  def grade
    (neki.present? and neki.first.r1) ? "A+" : "A-"
  end
end

# Controller
@neki = Neki.new(Anketare.where(...))

# View
<%= @neki.grade %>
```

Hope this helps!